# How to segue from UIAlert and pass information

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am pretty new to Swift and programming in general. I am making a quiz app and I want to transfer information between my quiz view controller and a new view controller. I have managed to successfully do that but now I want to use a `UIAlertView` to segue the information.

The problem I having is that when it transitions to the new view controller the arrays are not being populated. I had it working when I used a normal UI Button but with the UI alert it doesn't seem to work.

### User Submits Answers

When this button is pressed the program checks if the user has answered all the questions and then creates a `UIAlertView` - If the user presses Yes then it should segue to the next controller and pass the required information, but it doesn`t.

There is no issue with the arrays in the destination view controller as it has all been working fine until I decided to make this switch.

```
@IBAction func submitAll(sender: UIButton) {

    let hasAnsweredAllQuestions = questions.reduce(true) { (x, q) in x && (q.usersAnswer != nil) }

    println("has user answered all questions?: \(hasAnsweredAllQuestions)")

    if hasAnsweredAllQuestions == true {
            let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alert.delegate = self
            alert.title = "Submit Answers?"
            alert.message = "If you click yes, your answers will be submitted. If you aren`t finished with the exam press continue."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Yes")
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Continue")
            alert.show()
            println(userAnswers)

    } else if hasAnsweredAllQuestions == false {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Hey, Wait!"
        alert.message = "You have not answered all questions. Please finish the quiz."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

### Switch / Case Function

Here the program appends all the users responses and the correct answers to a new array and gets them ready to ship off to the next view controller.

As a mode of debugging I created a simple if statement that made sure the array was being populated.

Here the program segues into the next view controller but the arrays in the destination view controller are not being populated. It was originally working when I just used a simple `UIButton` and not an alert.

```
func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

    switch buttonIndex{
    case 0: // Yes

        for (index, _) in enumerate(questions) {
            userAnswers.append(questions[index].usersAnswer!)
            correctAnswers.append(questions[index].answer!)
            println("this is working")
        }

        if userAnswers.count == 4 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue.push.alert", sender: self)

            func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

                if(segue.identifier == "segue.push.alert") {
                    var answerSummary = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultsViewController

                    answerSummary.correctAnswersResults = correctAnswers
                    answerSummary.userAnswersResults = userAnswers
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    default: // Continue
        NSLog("Default");
        break;}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should know `UIAlertView` was deprecated a year ago. You shouldn't use it. `UIAlertController` is a suitable replacement for most purposes.

Comment: Oh wow! - That is embarassing. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method is embedded within your `alertView(_:clickedButtonAtIndex:)` method.

While this is legal in Swift, UIKit won't call this method. It needs to be a method within your view controller subclass (like your `alertView(_:clickedButtonAtIndex:)` method).

You may want to review some of the documentation on Xcode debugging; I think setting a breakpoint in the method would show you that it's never called.

Comment: Thanks for your help - Would you be abe to explain this a little more. I am struggling to understand what method needs to be called in my prepareForSegue.

Comment: You need to move your `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method so it's not inside of your `alertView(_:clickedButtonAtIndex:)` method.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are basically saying that it is impossible to segue and transfer the data from the UIAlert button? Otherwise I still don`t understand where I am supposed to move my prepareForSegue(_:sender:) to.

Comment: Nope, it will work fine. Just select from `func prepareFor…` down to the closing `}`, cut, move your cursor outside the `func alertView…` method scope, and paste.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have learned a great deal from this! It now works great :)

Comment: Glad to hear! If your issue is resolved, please click the check box to the left of my answer. This will signal to other users that you don't need more help.